# Multiclass Sigmoid for DRL action picking

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I am working on Deep reinforcement learning problem and I would like to use Sigmoid for my last layer instead of softmax. I am stuck on the what to use for action picking.

Specifically, How should I replace the last two line of this code and with what:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits) 

action = tf.squeeze(tf.multinomial(logits, num_samples=1), axis=-1)
y = tf.one_hot(action, n_outputs)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say last 2 layers of this code, I only see the output layer of your neural network.  Do you mean last 2 lines?  As in the code for action and y?

Comment: Yes, I meant that

Answer (score -1):

If you're converting from a softmax to a sigmoid function, it usually means you are converting from a multi classification problem into a binary classification problem.

Example multi-classification: Eat noodles, eat fish, eat meat, do not eat
Example binary classification: Eat, do not eat

In the multi classification case, your code is using the tf.multinomial function to select 1 action given log probabilities by your logits.  When you converted it into the binary case, it dramatically simplified the problem.  But it also completely changes the structure of your problem.

You can simply use for a sigmoid output:

```
if outputs < 0.5:
    action = 0
else:
    action = 1
```

where the action is no if the output is not 0.5, and yes if the output is greater than 0.5.

What your code did previously would be that for a binary classification, it would output a vector of 2 elements instead of a single scalar.  And the vector would have the probability of the yes and no action like this:

output = [P(no), P(yes)]

and your tf.one_hot converts the action selected using tf.multinomial to a one hot vector.  So if yes was selected, it would look like this:

y = [0, 1]

When you changed it to a sigmoid, you get a scalar of either 0 or 1, saying the action is yes or no.

Comment: What I want to find is not just get one answer for it, but get multiple answers. Not just choose one from list of food but choose couple or all. Also this is an Policy  gradient algorithm, I cannot just use if else and feed it back to optimization algorithm.

Comment: Hello Ahmet, to get multiple answers, you can simply loop the function above across all your outputs.   So then you'll have an array of 0s and 1s for the pick or not pick.  What confused me was that in your code, you put num_samples=1 for your tf.multinomial, specifying that you only want one output. Also, I don't really understand what you mean by you cannot feed back this solution back to the optimization algorithm.  All you need for the policy gradient is a cache of [States, Actions, Rewards, States (t + 1)).  You are defining your action in this case, so its an 1D array of 0s and 1s.